# JSP setting the value in text box but not showing

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, jsp

I am setting the value in text box

```
<input class="form-control table-cell input-sm" id="2_remoteFileActionValue" tabindex="26" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" value=".test3" data-original-title="Filter value">
```

but it's not showing in text box [image]

I have tried all this
like:

```
$("#2_remoteFileActionValue").val(".test3");

$("#2_remoteFileActionValue").attr("value",".test3");
```

but not working.
please help me out from this issue.
I tried out every thing but didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: for all we know your other config makes it appear on the last of six lines and you have to use your arrows to go down. can you provide more context (code) here?

Comment: check whether the text color is `white` or it is getting removed from js/Jquery